# How to check when a continuous aggregate job was last run on TimescaleDB

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have [continuous aggregate views](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/continuous-aggregates/) that should refresh automatically. However looks like no data is being written, or it is outdated. This may be misconfiguration, internal failure in TimescaleDB, etc. but in this point I only care to check which continuous aggregate views are properly being updated.

How to check when a specific continuous aggregate job was run last by its view name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Informational Views](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/informational-views/)

> TimescaleDB makes complex database features like partitioning and data retention easy to use with our comprehensive APIs. TimescaleDB works hard to provide detailed information about the state of your data, hypertables, chunks, and any jobs or policies you have in place.
>
> These views provide the data and statistics you need to keep track of your database.

[timescaledb_information.job_stats](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/informational-views/job_stats/):

> Shows information and statistics about jobs run by the automation framework. This includes jobs set up for user defined actions and jobs run by policies created to manage data retention, continuous aggregates, compression, and other automation policies. (See policies). The statistics include information useful for administering jobs and determining whether they ought be rescheduled, such as: when and whether the background job used to implement the policy succeeded and when it is scheduled to run next
>
> Sample usage
> Get job success/failure information for a specific hypertable.
>
> ```
> SELECT job_id, total_runs, total_failures, total_successes 
> FROM timescaledb_information.job_stats
> WHERE hypertable_name = 'test_table';
> ```
>
> Get information about continuous aggregate policy related statistics
>
> ```
> SELECT  js.* FROM
>    timescaledb_information.job_stats js, 
>    timescaledb_information.continuous_aggregates cagg
> WHERE cagg.view_name = 'max_mat_view_timestamp' 
>   and cagg.materialization_hypertable_name = js.hypertable_name;
>
>
> -[ RECORD 1 ]----------+------------------------------
> hypertable_schema      | _timescaledb_internal
> hypertable_name        | _materialized_hypertable_2
> job_id                 | 1001
> last_run_started_at    | 2020-10-02 09:38:06.871953-04
> last_successful_finish | 2020-10-02 09:38:06.932675-04
> last_run_status        | Success
> job_status             | Scheduled
> last_run_duration      | 00:00:00.060722
> next_scheduled_run     | 2020-10-02 10:38:06.932675-04
> total_runs             | 1
> total_successes        | 1
> total_failures         | 0
> ```

Comment: it seems all my hypertable table names are auto named like `_materialized_hypertable_4`. how do i figure out what their 'real' names are?